# What is the name of this tensor operation?

Tags: terminology, tensors

This is just a question about terminology, and likely has a very short answer, but I'm going to write down a long explanation.

**Background (standard linear algebra):**

If $L:\mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R^M$ is a linear transformation, a simple way to describe $L$ is to write down the matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{M \times N}$ such that $A(:,n) = L(e_n)$, where $e_n$ is the vector with a $1$ in the $n$th position and zeros elsewhere. (Here I'm using the Matlab-style notation $A(:,n)$ to denote the $n$th column of $A$.) If $x \in \mathbb R^N$, then we define the product of $A$ and $x$, denoted $Ax$, so that $Ax = L(x)$. Equivalently,
$$ 
Ax = \sum_n A(:,n) x_n.
$$
If $B \in \mathbb R^{K \times M}$, we define the product $C = BA \in \mathbb R^{K \times N}$ so that
$$
(BA) x = B(Ax) \quad \text{for all } x \in \mathbb R^N.
$$
Equivalently,
$$
(BA)(k,n) = \sum_m B(k,m) A(m,n) \quad \text{for all } 1 \leq k \leq K, 1 \leq n \leq N.
$$

---

**Extending the above ideas to multidimensional arrays:**

Now suppose that $L:\mathbb R^{N_1 \times N_2} \to \mathbb R^{M_1 \times M_2}$ is a linear transformation. A simple way to describe $L$ is to write down the multidimensional array $A \in \mathbb R^{M_1 \times M_2 \times N_1 \times N_2}$ such that
$A(:,:,n_1,n_2) = L(e_{n_1 n_2})$, where $e_{n_1 n_2} \in \mathbb R^{N_1 \times N_2}$ has a $1$ in position $(n_1,n_2)$ and zeros elsewhere. Applied mathematicians or machine learning people might call $A$ a "tensor", although it is merely a multidimensional array.

If $x \in \mathbb R^{N_1 \times N_2}$, we can define the "product" of $A$ with $x$, denoted $Ax$, so that
$$
Ax = L(x) = \sum_{n_1,n_2} A(:,:,n_1,n_2) x_{n_1 n_2}.
$$

If $B \in R^{K_1 \times K_2 \times M_1 \times M_2}$, we can define the "product"
$C = BA \in \mathbb R^{K_1 \times K_2 \times N_1 \times N_2}$ so that
$$
(BA)x = B(Ax) \quad \text{for all } x \in \mathbb R^N.
$$
Equivalently,
$$
(BA)(k_1,k_2,n_1,n_2) = \sum_{m_1,m_2} B(k_1,k_2,m_1,m_2) A(m_1,m_2,n_1,n_2) \quad \text{for all } k_1, k_2, n_1,n_2.
$$

**Question:** When $B$ and $A$ are "tensors" (multidimensional arrays) with compatible shapes, what is the name of this "product" $BA$ and what is the standard notation for it? I think the name and notation must indicate somehow which dimensions we are summing over, otherwise the meaning of the product could be ambiguous.

Comment: In index notation and with summation convention (repeated indices are summmed over), $Ax$ is the second rank tensor $A_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}\,x_{\gamma\delta}\,.$ Likewise, $BAx$ is the second rank tensor $B_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}A_{\gamma\delta\mu\nu}x_{\mu\nu}$ while $BA$ is the fourth rank tensor $B_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}A_{\gamma\delta\mu\nu}\,.$ The only name for those operations that comes to my mind is contraction.